# Correct function currying

Tags: javascript

I have such a function

```js
function addNum() {
  let sum = 0
  sum += 1

  function getNum() {
    return sum
  }

  addNum.getInnerNum = getNum

  return function() {
    return addNum
  }
}

addNum().getInnerNum() // 1
addNum()()().getInnerNum() // 3
addNum()()()()().getInnerNum() // 5
```

I need it to be called N times and calculate number of calls. So final result should be something like that

```
addNum().getInnerNum() // 1
addNum()()().getInnerNum() // 3
addNum()()()()().getInnerNum() // 5
```

Right now my code doesn't work and I have an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: addNum(...).getInnerNum is not a function)

The function doesn't calculate its calls.

Comment: `Uncaught ReferenceError: addOne is not defined` please fix that in the snippet.

Comment: fixed, incorrect word

Comment: Now throws `Uncaught TypeError: addNum(...).getInnerNum is not a function`. Please make sure you test your own code before posting.

Comment: that's why I created post because I do not know why this error appeared

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to do here, doesn't look like anything I've ever seen before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close the counter in `addNum` and return an inner function that increments the counter and returns itself:

```js
function addNum() {
    let n = 1

    function inner() {
        n += 1
        return inner
    }

    inner.getNum = () => n

    return inner

}


console.log(addNum()()()()()()()().getNum())
```

Answer (score 0):

The `let` has been initialized inside the function, so every time it will receive the value 1;

you can initialize the `let` outside the function and use the function to update the value

```js
let sum = 0;

function addNum(valueToAdd) {
  sum += valueToAdd

  function getNum() {
    return sum;
  }

  return {getNum};
}


console.log(addNum(1).getNum()) // 1
console.log(addNum(3).getNum()) // 3
console.log(addNum(5).getNum()) // 5
```

Another way is passing a number to the function with how many times this function should run, idk if it fits what you want

```js
function addNum(valueToAdd) {
  let sum = 0;
  sum += valueToAdd

  function getNum() {
    return sum;
  }

  return {getNum};
}


console.log(addNum(1).getNum()) // 1
console.log(addNum(3).getNum()) // 4
console.log(addNum(5).getNum()) // 9
```

With this idea of use props you can play and use any variable to control the iteration as `variable to change`, `number of times to parse`, `value to add`, etc.

Comment: addNum(...).getInnerNum is not a function

Comment: Your code has the same problem as the original, as you can see from the snippet demos I've created.

Comment: I'm sorry, I lose that parts

I'll edit